# Return Files w/o Note in at least X Days

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have a customer database and I'm trying to get all of the customer files that haven't had a comment on them in three weeks or more.

I'm working with two tables; the file table with info about the file like which staff is assigned to it, and the comments table, where all the comments in the database are.  They're linked by the file number field.

If I wanted the file number and date of last note, what SQL should I be using?

I have tried:

```
SELECT db_file_notes.file_num, Last(db_file_notes.file_date) AS 
LastOfnote_date, Last(db_file_notes.note_key) AS LastOfnote_key
FROM db_file_notes
GROUP BY db_file_notes.file_num
ORDER BY db_file_notes.file_num, Last(db_file_notes.note_date);
```

There are a handful of files that are on the resulting query that shouldn't be.  For example, file # 212720's last note was on 7/28, but the above query returns a last note date of 6/26 (the previous last note).  Then there's file # 212781 with actual last note on 7/21, but the query is return 6/12 (there five newer notes since the one returned by the query).

There's no date criteria in the above SQL but if I add the <=Date()-21 it's still incorrect (212710 is still there with a last note of 6/26).  Interestingly, if I add a filter on the file number to only return a single file number like 212720, the last note date returns correctly.

I've tried sorting by file number then note date, and file number and note key (on the general assumption that newer notes have higher key values) and get the same behavior.  Instead of sorting ascending then taking the last record, I've tried sorting descending and taking the first; this returns the correct note for the files affected by the above, but then new cases have the problem but in reverse now.

Comment: Try using `Max()` instead of `Last()`. Do you get expected results?

Comment: Using `MAX` as @Parfait said, or sort by `file_date` and `SELECT TOP 1`... _EDIT:_ Kind of scratch that as it doesn't answer the question, returns the one with the highest file_date though.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks a ton, I've poured like 14 hours into this since Friday.  If you don't mind, what's the difference between Max() and Last()?

Comment: A regular [Access question across many forums](https://www.google.com/search?q=Max+vs+Last+MS+Access&oq=Max+vs+Last+MS+Access&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1l2.1108.1108.0.1264.1.1.0.0.0.0.73.73.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.72.4d0Wv3qG7XY): `Max()` is the highest value in column while `Last()` is the latest record added which can be earlier dates.

Answer (score 0):

Sample table:
[image]

Without bringing in the second table you could use either of these:

This will return the top grouped date.  For example, if your maximum `file_date` is 12/06/2017 this will return all the records that have a file_date of 12/06/2017.

```
SELECT TOP 1  file_num
            , file_date
            , note_key
FROM        db_file_notes
WHERE       DATEDIFF("d",file_date,DATE())>=21
ORDER BY    file_date DESC
```

[image]

This code, on the other hand, will return the maximum date for each group of figures (a group being sets of `file_num` and `note_key`)

```
SELECT        file_num
            , MAX(file_date) AS Max_File_date
            , note_key
FROM        db_file_notes
WHERE       DATEDIFF("d",file_date,DATE())>=21
GROUP BY    file_num, note_key
```

[image]

Note:  You don't have to qualify each field name with the table name if the field is unique across all tables (or you're just using one table).